# About user Anonymous Coward

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-user-account

[This user](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/7104/anonymous-coward) seems to be the [same one on MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1164/recent-questions-in-complexity-theory/) which has posted several questions on MathOverflow without following them up and the questions are left there.

Now the user has started doing the same thing here, and she/he doesn't reply to the comments to clarify the questions and does not seem to care about them being answered or not.

How should we deal with this? Should we close these questions because of their vagueness and non-responsiveness of the asker as "not a real question" (based on our policies)? Or do you think there is a better way to deal with this?

(The reason I am asking this is that it seems the user is probably a graduate student in TCS and the questions can end up being interesting if we can make her/him reply to the comments and clarify her/his questions.)

Comment: The answer to the #P question was great. At least that question is a net positive for the site. If no one answers because the question can't be answered (because the asker won't clarify) then I would be happy to vote to close. But I would suggest dealing on a case by case basis.

Comment: I don't think these are homework problems (conceivably the last one might be, but the rest probably aren't), so I don't think answering them is bad. We should treat them on a case-by-case basis.